# Track detailed status GCM notification after post

Tags: php, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have sent the GCM notifications to android users from the server (PHP code) and the notification perfectly sent to the concern users.

Now I want to track the detailed delivery status of notification which I have sent by using any automated process.

For example if I sent a notification then I receive a message id as response i.e. **0:1462789232817777%8d4c7159f9fd7ecd**

and If I want to track its detailed story then I need to do it manually from  GCM Diagnostics by entering the message id which gives me output as 
[image]

But I want a automated process/api from which I can get this information.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the parameter `delivery_receipt_requested` as `yes` while you are sending the notification.

Which means google will hit your server while the device receives the notification, After updating the status on the server you can track the status of receiving notification. But for this you need to use XMPP protocol instead of HTTP.